# Printing a square dot board

Tags: python

I need to make a program in python to print a square board consisting of dots. The size is input by the user (between 2x2 and 9x9 squares) eg 4x4 =

```
. . . .
. . . .
. . . .
. . . .
```

The program asks the user for the int value between 2-9 and prints the board.
eg board_size? 4

Comment: StackOverflow isn't meant as a "write code for me" platform. As John and Felix are hinting... what have you tried, im assuming youve tried something, right?

Answer (score 1):

I'm telling your teacher where you got this from:

```
(w, h) = [int(i) for i in raw_input().split('x')]
print (". "*w + "\n") * h
```

Comment: Too see what's going on, `'a'+'a'`->`'aa'`, and `'a'*5`->`'aaaaa'`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your answer using generator expressions.  It's basically the same as using a list comprehension in this case except that it does double the work while still being semi-Pythonic.  It didn't really need to come to this, but I forced it to be this bad.  Aside from being completely difficult to read and less than compact in its design, you might get great marks for this program!

```
sz = 4
line_gen = (((' ' for i in range(sz)), ('.' for i in range(sz))) for i in range(sz))
for line in line_gen:
    print(''.join((space.join((dot for dot in line[0])) for space in line[1])))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very challenging problem.

```
w,x,h=raw_input("board_size?")
exec"print'. '*int(w);"*int(h)
```

is probably the most straight forward way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Here is your homework (being s the size of the square):

```
print "\n".join ( [" ".join ( ["." for i in range (s) ] ) for j in range (s) ] )
```

Just scan the size s from stdin or wherever the user inputs it.